# Entity Framework Relationship Problems

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to keep track if a car part has been recorded as repaired between local headquarters and state headquarters. I am getting an additional field called Car_Vin in my Parts tables. In addition, when I grab the the records associated with a car my records collections always come back as empty. Could someone explain why these two issues are happening?

```
public Car
{
    [Key]
    public string VIN{get;set;}
    //More fields go here
    public virtual ICollection<StateHQRecord> StateHQRecords{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<LocalHQRecord> LocalHQRecords{get;set;}
}

public Part{
{
    [Key]
    public string PartNumber{get;set;}
    //More fields go here
    public virtual ICollection<StateHQRecord> StateHQRecords{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<LocalHQRecord> LocalHQRecords{get;set;}
}

public class StateHQRecord
{
    public string VIN{get;set;}
    public string PartNumber{get;set;}
    public Car Car{get;set;}
    public Part Part{get;set;}
    public bool isRepaired{get;set;}
}

public class LocalHQRecord
{
    public string VIN{get;set;}
    public string PartNumber{get;set;}
    public Car Car{get;set;}
    public Part Part{get;set;}
    public bool isRepaired{get;set;}
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<StateHQRecord>().HasKey(te => new {te.VIN, te.PartNumber});
        modelBuilder.Entity<StateHQRecord>().Map(m => m.ToTable("StateHQRecords"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocalHQRecord>().HasKey(te => new {te.VIN, te.PartNumber});
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocalHQRecord>().Map(m => m.ToTable("LocalHQRecords")); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasKey(a => a.VIN);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().
                HasMany(a => a.StateHQRecords).
                WithRequired(te => te.Car).
                HasForeignKey(te => te.VIN);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().
                HasMany(a => a.LocalHQRecords).
                WithRequired(te => te.Car).
                HasForeignKey(te => te.VIN);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Part>().HasKey(a => a.PartNumber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Part>().
                HasMany(a => a.StateHQRecords).
                WithRequired(te => te.Part).
                HasForeignKey(te => te.PartNumber);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Part>().
                HasMany(a => a.LocalHQRecords).
                WithRequired(te => te.Part).
                HasForeignKey(te => te.PartNumber);

}


public void AddCarToLocalHQ(Car car,Part part)
{
    var currentCarEntityState=EntityState.Modified;
    var currentPartEntityState=EntityState.Modified;
    var currentCar=context.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.VIN==car.VIN);
    var currentPart=context.Parts.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.PartNumber==part.PartNumber);

    if(currentCar==null)
    {
        currentCar=car;
        currentCarEntityState=EntityState.Added;
    }
    if(currentPart==null)
    {
        currentPart=part;
        currentPartEntityState=EntityState.Added;
    }

    var currentRecord=context.LocalHQRecords.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.VIN==currentCar.VIN && r.PartNumber==currentPart.PartNumber);
    if(currentRecord!=null)
    {
        throw new DuplicateRecordException();
    }

    currentRecord=new LocalHQRecord{Car=currentCar,Part=currentPart};
    currentCar.LocalHQRecords.Add(currentRecord);
    currentPart.LocalHQRecords.Add(currentRecord);
    context.Entry(currentCar).State=currentCarEntityState;
    context.Entry(currentPart).State=currentPartEntityState;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```